# Bizarre Skype automatic logout issue

Tags: login, skype

I am having this problem since a few months:

on my home PC (windows 8.1) when I start the Skype desktop app, it logins into my Skype account, but after a second it logs out and shows the starting dialog (see screenshot below), where I must enter my account name and password again to log in. Then everything works until the next time I start Skype when the same problem happens again.

The showed login dialog:

[image]

At that time, the Skype credentials disappear from Control Panel / Credential Manager (where they are usually stored and visible, when the Skype login works - see below an example):

[image]

I use the same Skype account on my iPhone and iPad and work PC (Windows 7) and there is never an issue.

I tried:

- reinstalling Skype
- clearing all saved state, including the Skype login credentials in Windows Credential Manager
- updating the Skype app (several updates were released in that time)

Nothing helps.

The only thing I found was a workaround:

- start Windows
- login to Windows
- open Control Panel / Credential Manager
- start Skype

I am doing this since a month, and it never fails. Today I started Skype without opening Credential Manager first, and *bam*, it logged me out again.

Currently I have Skype version 8.55

For reference, this is how Credential Manager looks when my Skype login is remembered:

[image]

There is a reddit discussion about this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/skype/comments/dnwbdm/skype_keeps_forgetting_my_login_name_and_password/) and there a discussion on [Microsoft Skype community forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/how-do-i-stop-skype-8-automatically-signing-me-out/01393ece-94b1-4039-91ee-36c5cb619a60) is linked, with some users having the same problem, but no solution.

Comment: Try to run Skype once as Admin, enter credentials, and then exit.

Comment: Try to remove your microsoft account completely from windows, log in again. I think it should work then

Comment: @SrinivasV I have no microsoft account.

Comment: @DavidBalažic: Did you try to run Skype as Admin?

Comment: @harrymc it will take several days to see if that helped.

Comment: Try to return here before your bounty elapses.

Comment: you need to store it as a generic credential

Comment: @DeerSpotter How to do that? Until now I just entered my username and password in the Skype app, when it asked for it.

Comment: ...and it's back! After this problem went away (so Skype was working OK, no logouts), a few days ago it logged me out again. Will report more details as they come in.

Answer (score 1):

Try the old fix of running Skype once as Administrator, entering fully the credentials,
then exiting and passing on to normal running.

This trick allows the program to update some parameter that it is stuck
on trying to update, but cannot manage to do because of some snarl-up of
permissions, and this may also reset those permissions.

This trick has worked for me, although for other products,
and may also work for Skype.

Comment: awarding bounty, even if not tested yet (in past it worked fine for days, and then logged out, so it is hard to tell if something actually helped or not).

Comment: It didn't help. I started Skype as Administrator on 18.2.2020 and today, on 29.2.2020, so only 11 days later it logged me out after start.

Comment: I understand then that it did work for 11 days. You could try to redo this, if whenever and whatever is the problem happens again.

Comment: No, the same thing happened without running as Admin. It works OK for days, then one day stops. Running it as Admin did not make any difference.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall Skype, scrub the disk and registry for every mention of the string "Skype", then reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

Skype for Desktop MSA/david.balazic

- username
- password

Skype for Desktop/david.balazic

- username
- password

david.balazic

- username
- password

now enter also another with just the **username**

- username
- password

Comment: How? If click "Add a generic credential", I must also enter "Internet or network address".

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out:

1. Uninstall Skype
2. Go to `...\AppData\Roaming` directory (press `Windows + R` and type `%appdata%` then enter)
3. Delete (or rename) 2 folders: `Skype` and `Microsoft\Skype for Desktop`
4. Reinstall Skype

I found out that the size of  old `Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Cache` folder was too big, which could be a core reason.